# Java | How to close a JFrame while a "forever" loop is running?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

I programmed myself a little helper-tool. It got a little GUI with the buttons "Run" and "Stop". If I press "Run" the program executes a loop that continuously does something (http requests - every hour a few ones).

But now I have the problem that, when I press "Run", the button stays pressed and the program/GUI waits for the process to end. In this time I can't close the Window or press the "Stop"-button. And because the process is running forever, I am never able to end it - of course I can end the process in task-manager.

Is there a way to bypass this problem?

I look forward for a helpful answer ;-)

Comment: Start a new thread for running the forever loop.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: And thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

Without code one can only speculate, but you are most likely running everything on the same thread, meaning that the method which handles the button press also launches these requests.

The problem with this approach is that everything is done on the Event Dispatching Thread, which is the thread which handles events and other UI operations. Any lengthy operations on this thread will make your UI non responsive.

To solve this problem, you will need to have your `Run` event handler launch threads which do all the work. This will leave the EDT free to handle user interactions.

Comment: Thank you sir, it works fine now!
I guess editing my first post with the source code is not necessary anymore :-)